# PyViz: Having trouble displaying visualizations side by side

Tags: python, visualization

I'm following the PyViz tutorial found here: http://pyviz.org/tutorial/01_Workflow_Introduction.html, and I am running into an issue with displaying images side by side when using the exact code from the tutorial (in the New York vs Texas Measles example).

I should mention that I did not download the conda environment as outlined in the tutorial. I opened a new Jupyter Notebook, installed all the specified libraries(I hope), and downloaded the examples from the PyViz github page.

The libraries I downloaded/imported are the following:

```
    import holoviews as hv
    import bokeh
    import matplotlib
    import pandas as pd
    import datashader
    import dask
    import geoviews
    import numpy as np
    import hvplot.pandas
    import hvplot
    import holoviews as hv
    hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib', width="100")
```

The part of the tutorial code that does not work is the following:

```
by_state["Texas"].relabel('Texas') + by_state["Florida"].relabel('Florida')
```

Both statements run on their own, but the plus sign does not appear to work. The error states:

> TypeError: gridplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'

The rest of the tutorial runs smoothly. Does anyone have any insight into what could be going wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: The pyviz webpage seems to be reorganized, your link is no longer working. Likewise the tutorial is also revised.